# Can one describe product in monomial ideals with only one generator

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Given $I = (u_1,...,u_n)$ a monomial ideal and $G(u_i)$ the minimal generating system, $J=(v)$ another monomial ideal in a ring $S$, then $I:(v) = \{f\in S| fg \in I \,\,\forall g \in (v)\}.$ Let $w$ be an arbitrary element in $I:(v).$ Then, $wv \in I,$ whereby $v$ is the generator of $J.$ In the book I am reading, it says, there exists a generator $u_i \in I$ such that $wv = w'u_i$ for some $w'\in S.$ I do not understand how can in general a single generator suffice to describe $wv \in I.$ In fact, one should write $wv = \sum_{j=1}^n r_ju_j.$ It is unclear to my that one can find a generator $u_i$ such that $wv = \sum_{j=1}^n r_ju_j \stackrel{?}{=} w'u_i.$ If one factorizes $u_i,$ it must not always be the case that $u_i|r_j \, \forall j\in\{1,...,n\},$ where $u_i$ is (as said above) a monomial and $r_j$ polynomials in $S.$ Can somebody provide some insight? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I=\langle av, bv\rangle$ with $G(I)=\{av,bv\}$ and $J=\langle v \rangle$.

The condition $fg\in I$ is equivalent to $fv\in I$. For an element $w=a+b\in S$, we have $wv\in I$. Thus $w\in (I:(v))$. Here, $wv=av+bv$ is not a multiple of $a$, nor $b$.

So, from what you described $wv=\sum_{j=1}^n r_ju_j$, and to have $wv=w'u_i$ for some $w'\in S, u_i\in G(I)$, we must have
$$
\frac{u_i}{\gcd(u_i,u_j)}\big| r_j \ \ \mbox{ if } j\neq i.
$$
Here, for $j=i$, the term $r_iu_i$ is already a multiple of $u_i$.